# Tasty pie search

Tags: tastypie

i have two models

```
class Business(Basetable):
name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
logo=models.OneToOneField("BusinessLogo",null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Address(models.Model):
business = models.ForeignKey("Business", related_name='biz_address')
address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
state = models.ForeignKey(States,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
city = models.ForeignKey(City,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

view.py

```
class BusinessResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    queryset = Business.objects.filter(status='P').order_by('-id')
    resource_name = 'business'
    filtering = {
        'is_black_business': ALL,         
        'city': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,

    }
 def dehydrate(self,bundle):
 if buss_address.city:bundle.data['city'] = buss_address.city.name
        else:bundle.data['city'] = ''
   // i am getting city here
```

problem is i need to filter the business using city .. how can i do that ? any guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class BusinessResource(ModelResource):
   addresses = fields.ToManyField(AddressResource, 'biz_address')
   class Meta:
       filtering = {
                    'addresses': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
                 }

class AddressResource(ModelResource):
    city = fields.ToOneField(CityResource, 'city')
    class Meta:
       filtering = {
                     'city': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
                    }
```

Second way is to write custom filter by overriding build_filters and apply_filters methods.

Comment: You could get my mail from my profile, but better way is to post your questions here, in that way more people will have benefits from them and you will get more reliable answers.